# Dynamic form component markAsDirty() Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an app with a dynamic forms component which is something like this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g3a7cm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform.component.ts&devtoolsheight=50

The form.component loads a schema and some data from the server. If data was loaded for a particular field it marks it as dirty by calling markAsDirty(). This is so if dirty autosaved data is loaded proper validation messages can be displayed immediately.

There is also a form-field.component which has a function that evaluates a disabled condition and disables/enables the field.

I'm getting the error the first time any field on the form is disabled.

If I comment out either of these lines the error goes away:

form.component.ts:50
form-field.component.ts:42

Anybody have any good idea why this is happening and how I might fix it?

I have looked at other similar questions but none seem to be the same as my specific issue.

Thanks for looking.

edit:

Also, if I put the initial call to evalDisabled() in a setTimeout it fixes it. (form-field.component.ts:32) I thought the point of reactive forms was that they were supposed to allow synchronous logic. Why should I have to do this?

Comment: Still are you facing this issue or expecting good solution?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look but I have already worked around this issue. Turns out it is a bug related to ngFor. If you're interested you can find details here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24563

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link